# Can i auto generate a key like pt1234 or 12pt34 or p12t34

Tags: mysql

I want to auto generate the unique id for every user like abc123 or ab1234c or ab12c34 . Is there any solution. If so kindly share with me.

Comment: And what is wrong with `AUTO_INCREMENT`? It auto generates a unique id for each entry and you can bring that numerical if to what ever form you want.

Comment: Problem is not with AUTO_INCREMENT . Problem is that how i generate the numerical as well as the alphabet key i:e pt1234

Comment: That depends what the rules of generating that key is. The same method used to convert decimal to hexadecimal could be used to convert a decimal to a key that has a combination of alphanumeric chars. So do you really need a new key or just another representation of your auto_increment key.

Comment: I need anthor representation of the auto_increment key which contian alphanumeric chars